# Appropiate ways of treating Inf or NA ratio variables for xgboost or random forest

Tags: neural-network, random-forest, xgboost, feature-engineering

I have several variables ordered by date, and I would like to take the ratios of growth from one month to the next one. I understand that it is normal to loose the first value.
But my question is, how should i replace the infinite values in ratios where the lag value was zero (by replacement of NA or because it was actually zero)
For example:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date= c("01-01-2020",
            "01-02-2020","01-03-2020","01-01-2020",
            "01-02-2020","01-03-2020"),
  id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
  var1 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 5L),
  var2 = c(0L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L)
)
example

example_g <- example %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(var1_lag = (var1 - dplyr::lag(var1, 1))/dplyr::lag(var1, 1),
         var2_lag = (var2 - dplyr::lag(var2, 1))/dplyr::lag(var2, 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
example_g
```

What are good approaches for random forest, neural nets or xgboost?
I would think that for tree based methods simply replacing Inf/-Inf by something like 99999/-99999 would suffice, but i'm not sure if i'm missing something, and if that would work for neural nets.
Has anyone faced a problem like this? what did you do?